# Collection not saved mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections

I have an issue on my application (mongodb/nodejs), my aim is to save a collection :

```
const Job = require("../models/Job");
exports.saveJob = (req, res, next) => {
    const newJob = new Job(req.body);
    newJob.gender = 'Male';
    newJob.save((err, myjob) => {
        myjob.code = '1234';
        myjob.save((err, mysavedjob) => {

            console.log(mysavedjob);
            /** OUTPUT **
            * { __v: 0,
                updatedAt: 2018-07-31T08:31:47.664Z,
                createdAt: 2018-07-31T08:31:47.664Z,
                gender:'Male',
                code:'1234',
                ...
             }
            */

        })
    })
}
```

As you can see, the code output the saved document, but when I check the database , I don't have the code:'1234' I have just

```
{ __v: 0,
 updatedAt: 2018-07-31T08:31:47.664Z,
 createdAt: 2018-07-31T08:31:47.664Z,
 gender:'Male',
  ...
}
```

**==== UPDATE (adding the JobModel) ====**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    code: String,
    gender: String,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Job", JobSchema, "jobs");
```

Someone could tell me why please ?
thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to share the job model?

Comment: Hey, thank you,i just updated the post.

Comment: You're code works as expected.  I've created a standalone version of your code maybe this will help you https://github.com/peterjgrainger/mongoose-sandbox.  I'm not sure how you are handling connections or how you are checking the database or the data you already have in there so that may be a factor?

Comment: To run it you need to stop any local copy of mongo running then `docker-compose up -d` then  `node app.js`

Comment: @PeterGrainger i remove all datas from the database, and re-do the insert/update but same scenario.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the code you posted, I ran it locally myself and all was good :)  Checked the database everything is in there including the code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the correct way to alter a job after saving it but try this

```
const Job = require("../models/Job");
exports.saveJob = (req, res, next) => {
const newJob = new Job(req.body);
newJob.gender = 'Male';
newJob.save((err, myjob) => {
    myjob.code = '1234';

    Job.findOneAndUpdate({_id: myjob._id}, myjob, (err, mysavedjob) => {
        console.log(mysavedjob);
    });

})
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping me, the second options will create another document?

Comment: Yes, it will, my bad. I will edit that out. From my experience, save() only lets me save to new. I normally would use findOneAndUpdate() for the efficiency.

Also how come you are setting the job code after you have created the job?

Comment: Thank you but findOneAndUpdate not working either, i deleted this part and surprise, the myjob.code is saved, wtf?